# Test works, but it's too slow for the test

Tags: ruby, performance

Hi guys I spent a while with my pairing partner solving this problem https://www.codewars.com/kata/playing-on-a-chessboard/train/ruby

It passes every test but has a `STDERR` at the end saying:

```
Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete.
```

Can anyone please advise on how to speed the following code up or make it more efficient?

```
def game(n)
  # lowest common multiplier
  mult = (1..2*n).to_a.reduce(1,:lcm)
  y = 1
  x = 1
  # numerator sum
  numsum = 0

  while y <= n
    while x <= n
      # 
      numsum += x * mult / (x + y)
      x += 1
    end
    x = 1; y += 1
  end

  array = [Rational(numsum, mult).numerator, Rational(numsum, mult).denominator]
  if array[1] == 1
    [array[0]]
  else 
    array
  end

end
```

Comment: Not shown: The test case which is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following part of your code:

```
while y <= n
  while x <= n 
    numsum += x * mult / (x + y)
    x += 1
  end
  x = 1; y += 1
end
```

Note that you have 2 nested loops, each one with `n` iterations.
That means your code has a complexity of **O(n²)** (you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Thus, if you call the `game` function with a high value of `n`, your code may hang.

I suggest you to try to rethink your algorithm.
Probably exists another more efficient way to solve your problem.